# Is there any major query performance difference between IN, NOT IN operators compared to AND/OR

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any major query performance difference between IN and NOT IN operators compared to AND/OR

Comment: It depends.  A more specific example would be allow a more useful answer.

Comment: Yes, it depends.  Your best bet is to set it up both ways and benchmark based on execution time and review of explain plan.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This is apparently your first question, so I will delete this comment later. Please have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I'd say generally there is no difference between `IN` or `OR`. However, it's better to verify this by looking at the query plans:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT object_type AS c FROM all_objects;
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(null,'T');

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT * FROM T WHERE c IN ('INDEX', 'TABLE', 'SYNONYM');

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
...
   1 - filter("C"='INDEX' OR "C"='SYNONYM' OR "C"='TABLE')
```

So, internally, Oracle converts the `IN` into a list of `OR`, at least for this example.

The version with `OR` generates exactly the same query plan and has therefore exactly the same performance as the version with `IN`:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN 
FOR SELECT * FROM T WHERE c='INDEX' OR c='TABLE' OR c='SYNONYM';

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
   1 - filter("C"='INDEX' OR "C"='SYNONYM' OR "C"='TABLE')
```

`NOT IN` seems to be converted into an `AND` list:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT * FROM T WHERE c NOT IN ('INDEX', 'TABLE', 'SYNONYM');

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

   1 - filter("C"<>'INDEX' AND "C"<>'TABLE' AND "C"<>'SYNONYM')
```